# The kernel linux's lookup_address function in x86 returns NULL when debugging a specific case of Page Fault

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, segmentation-fault, page-tables, page-fault

I have implemented a simple hook function inside the `arch/x86/mm/fault.c`, using a kernel (general-purpose) v6.1.
This function is like this:

```c
void is_read_only(unsigned long addr)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    if(pte == NULL)
        printk(KERN_WARNING "--------> Page not present");
    else if pte_write(*pte)
        printk(KERN_WARNING "--------> Page is writable");
    else
        printk(KERN_WARNING "--------> Page is readonly");
}
```

I call this function inside [`__bad_area_nosemaphore`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L850) immediatly below the `show_signal_msg` call. I give the virtual address as argument to the `is_read_only`.

A very known case of Page Fault (PF) / Segmentation Fault example for linux I've used is this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *str = "Hello, world!";

int main()
{
    printf("%s", str);
    str[0] = 'h';
    return 0;
}
```

This example returns the **error code 7**, the line below is produced on syslog:

```
segfault at 562642b30004 ip 0000562642b2f16d sp 00007fffb58ac2a0 error 7 in a.out[562642b2f000+1000] likely on CPU 0 (core 0, socket 0)
```

By consulting the Intel Manual, it turns out that the error code 7 means that:

- Bit 0 is on, indicating that when the PF occurred the page was present.
- Bit 1 is on, indicating that when the PF occurred the processor was in user mode.
- Bit 2 is on, indicating that when the PF occurred it was in writing operation.

If error 7 means that the page was present, why `lookup_address` is returning NULL?
Wasn't it supposed to return the Page Table Entry correctly?